# r - Empty textInput() causing error in leaflet shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, textinput

I have a shiny app that plots data from an API on a leaflet map. It also takes 2 inputs from the user that are passed through to the `API call`.

One of those is a text input that sets the region for which the `API` should pull data. If the user types in an incorrect region code or simply deletes the code, the shiny app gives an error and then you have to type in a correct code and wait for the app to get back on track. It's clumsy and looks bad.

I tried to get around it by using `if(is.null(APIdata()))` with an `if{}else{}` (see code below), but this literally did not change anything. I thought it would work, and I'm fine with the idea of it just popping back to an empty leaflet. Is there something else I can do?

**Error:**

```
Error: parse error: premature EOF

                     (right here) ------^
```

and

```
Warning: Error in : parse error: premature EOF

                     (right here) ------^

Stack trace (innermost first):
    96: parse_string
    95: parseJSON
    94: fromJSON_string
    93: jsonlite::fromJSON
    92: ebird_GET
    91: ebirdnotable
    90: <reactive:APIdata> [/Users/Guest/Desktop/eBirdRarity/app.R#41]
    79: APIdata
    78: func [/Users/Guest/Desktop/eBirdRarity/app.R#68]
    77: origRenderFunc
    76: output$myMap
     1: runApp
```

**Code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(rebird)

ui <- bootstrapPage(

    theme = shinytheme("superhero"),

    # Setting map to full-screen
    tags$style(type="text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),

    # Initializing leaflet output
    leafletOutput("myMap", width="100%", height="100%"),

    # Adding title overlayed on leaflet map
    absolutePanel(top = 1, left = 50, draggable = T, 
                  titlePanel("eBird Recent Rarities Viewer")),

    # Adding slider input overlayed on leaflet map
    absolutePanel(bottom = 1, left = 45, draggable = T, 
                  sliderInput("slider_in", "Days Back", min = 1, max = 30, value = 14, round = T)),

    # Adding text input overlayed on leaflet map
    absolutePanel(top = 1, right = 45, draggable = T,
                  textInput("region_in", "Region Code", value = "US-MA", placeholder = "US-MA"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Rendering data frame from API with slider input
  APIdata <- reactive({

    # Initial fetch of data from eBird API
    a <- ebirdnotable(region = as.character(input$region_in), back = as.numeric(input$slider_in))

    # Changing review status from logical to numeric
    cols <- sapply(a, is.logical)
    a[,cols] <- lapply(a[,cols], as.numeric)

    # Initializing new date column
    a["date"] <- format(strptime(a$obsDt, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), "%b %d")

    # Initializing new color grouping column
    a["group"] <- NA

    # Assigning colors by review status
    idx<-  (a$obsReviewed == 0) # Not reviewed
    a$group[idx] <- "white"
    idx<- (a$obsReviewed == 1) & (a$obsValid == 1) # Reviewed and accepted
    a$group[idx] <- "green"

    # Jittering lat/lon points to fix point overlap
    a$lat = jitter(a$lat, factor = 3) 

    # print(a)
    return(a)
  })

  # Leaflet map
  output$myMap = renderLeaflet({
    if(is.null(APIdata()))
    {
      # Rendering leaflet map
      return(leaflet() %>% addTiles()) %>%
        addSearchOSM(options = searchOSMOptions(zoom = 8))
    }
    else
    {
      # Splitting up by review status in order to show reviewed on top
      notReviewed = APIdata()[APIdata()$group == "white",]
      accepted = APIdata()[APIdata()$group == "green",]

      # Rendering leaflet map
      leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = notReviewed, color = "white", opacity = 0.7, label = paste(notReviewed$comName,", ",notReviewed$date, ", ", notReviewed$locName,sep = "")) %>% # , labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = F, direction = 'auto')) %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = accepted, color = "green", opacity = 0.7, label = paste(accepted$comName,", ",accepted$date, ", ", accepted$locName, sep = "")) %>% # , labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = F, direction = 'auto')) %>%
      addLegend(position = "bottomright", 
                  colors = c("#FFFFFF", "#008000"), 
                  labels = c("Not reviewed", "Accepted"),
                  title = "Legend: review status", opacity = 1) %>%
      addSearchOSM(options = searchOSMOptions(zoom = 8))
    }
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to validate the input before going to the api? Why are you allowing users to submit invalid data at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just validate if you are getting a `tibble` with values or if you are getting an empty `tibble`. In case the `tibble` is empty you can return `NULL`. This way the validation you have added to check if  `APIdata()` is `NULL` would work.

You could just add `if(length(a) == 0){return(NULL)}` after `a <- ebirdnotable(region = as.character(input$region_in), back = as.numeric(input$slider_in))` in your reactive for it to work.

**EDIT:**

As you mentioned in your comment you can actually use `try` here. That would mean adding one more condition in addition to above condition the code would be something like this:

```
 a <- try(ebirdnotable(region = as.character(input$region_in), back = as.numeric(input$slider_in)))
          if(class(a) == "try-error" ||length(a) == 0){return(NULL)}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for this! Great idea. I have included that line, but it actually still throws an error for some types of inputs. For example, when I type in "US-M" (deleting the "A") or "US-", it does what I want and pops out to an empty leaflet. But if I delete back to "U", then it throws the the same error as before `premature EOF`. I just checked in a blank script document and its the `ebirdnotable()` that is printing that exact error with some inputs. But it still produces a 0x0 tibble.

Comment: Could I implement `tryCatch()` here? I haven't used that before.

Comment: @Heliornis you are right, you can use try here. I have edited the code have a look.